# Существительные на -ие в предложном падеже

Tags: орфография

Чего-то недопонимаю! Вот предложение:

> Евсеич в продолжение этих тяжелых пяти недель сделался совершенно моим дядькой, и я очень полюбил его.

Недавно в одной из книг я прочёл, что существительные на -ие в предложном падеже должны оканчиваться на -и! Ведь слово-продолжение оканчивается на -ие и это существительное, в данном случае оно стоит в предложном падеже, так почему оно не оканчивается на -и ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сочетания "в течение", "в продолжение", "вследствие", "в заключение" (и некоторые другие) - это предлоги.
Отличить их от соответвующих существительных можно с помощью вопроса, предлоги не отвечают на вопрос "в чем?", только "когда?" (реже "где?") - обычно вместе с последующим существительным.
Если так понятнее, то в подобных составных предлогах сушествительное стоит не в предложном, а в винительном падеже: "во что?" - "в течение". Именно так понималось отношение времени нашими предками. Сравните: "в жару", "в полдень", "в праздники".

Comment: Простите, позволила себе исправить опечатку, пока кто-то не обвинил Вас в ошибке.

Comment: спасибо. А какую? Вы же знаете, я леплю их без меры (о причинах пока умолчу), но ошибка ошибке - рознь.

Comment: Вследствие - предлог пишется слитно. Уверена, что это опечатка.Можете удалить комментарий.

Comment: Не, не буду. Это действительно тянет на ошибку. )))

Answer (score 0):

Нет. В данном случае "в продолжение" - это предлог. Есть правило, что если "в течение" и "d продолжение" употребляются с указанием времени, то это предлоги и пишутся на -ие. В противном случае, они склоняются как обычно. Примеры:
"В течении реки был найден утопленник."
"В продолжении сериала появился новый актер."